# Change button value using onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the value of an input button using an onclick function but no matter what I do I can't seem to get it working, and none of the answers I've found on here have seemed to help.

```js
function button() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("tz");
  if (btn.value == "UTC") {
    btn.value = "Local time";
  } else {
    btn.value = "UTC";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="tz" onclick="button()" value="UTC">
```

Comment: As you can see, the code you've provided works just fine. Can you check console (`F12` while you have the page active)? Perhaps something elsewhere on the page is causing your code to break before getting here, the function might be undefined due to scoping, an external JS file is not being imported properly, etc.

Comment: The only reason why this wouldn't work is if the `button` function is not defined in global scope (which could be either because you really didn't declare it in global scope or there is an error in some other part of the code that prevents the browser from evaluating this code).

Comment: Perhaps I should've mentioned. I'm using a Chromebook so I can't exactly press F12 and I'm otherwise unsure of how to access the console since the one I'm using is limited in terms of its functionality. I'm also not in a web browser (I'm using Chrome Dev Editor to write this program).

Comment: @Berry    On a Chromebook, you can right-click on any specific element (in this example, the button) and then select "Inspect Element" to get to the DevTools

Comment: @Berry The alternative shortcut is `CTRL + SHIFT + J` I believe, for future reference.

Comment: @aman.s That's just the issue, my Chromebook is limited in its functionality. I'm not able to use Inspect Element, I'd have to request the administrator to enable it for me.

Comment: @Berry Well, doing our best with what we've got, where is your function declared? In the <head>? The <body>? Importing it from an external JS file? And is it wrapped in anything else, or is it literally just `<script> *function here* </script>`? Is there code *before* the function declaration that could be breaking?

Comment: @TylerRoper It's coming from an external JS file. The script is wrapped in a window.onload function.

Comment: @Berry Well, that my friend is your problem. You're defining the function inside of the `window.onload`, so it will only be accessible inside of the `window.onload` (not globally, like where your button is trying to call it from). Take the function declaration *out* of the `window.onload` function, or an even better option, keep the `window.onload` and make use of [event bindings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of an inline `onclick` event.

Comment: @TylerRoper Moving it outside of the onload function didn't work, but using event bindings did. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Its a case of .value vs .innerHTML...  You are changing the .value (and it works) but you aren't also updating the button.innerHTML (a label... not the value)...

```
<script>
function changeValue(button) {
  console.log('The original value of the button is: ', button.value, ' and the innerHTML is: ', button.innerHTML);
  if (button.value == "UTC") {
    button.value = "Local time";
    console.log('Now the value has changed to: ', button.value, ' but the innerHTML has not: ', button.innerHTML);
    button.innerHTML = "Local time";
    console.log('The new value of the button is still: ', button.value, ' but now the innerHTML is also changed: ', button.innerHTML);
  } 
}
```

```
<button id="tz" type="button" value="UTC" onClick="changeValue(this);" name="button">UTC</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was utilizing event bindings. Using Tyler Roper's suggestion, all I had to do to get this to work under my particular circumstances was add an event listener for the button function and omit the inline onclick event altogether.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("tz");

function button() {
  if (btn.value == "UTC") {
    btn.value = "Local time";
  } else {
    btn.value = "UTC";
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", button, false);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="tz" value="UTC"></input>
```